# Storage location of video tags in Windows Live Photo Gallery

Tags: windows-7, video, metadata, windows-live

I know that Windows Live Photo Gallery 2011 stores people tags and other metadata like ratings in the photos themselves ([see a very similar question about **photos** here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9753/where-are-people-tags-stored-when-edited-with-windows-live-photo-gallery)).

I'd like to know if the program does the same for video files, which also can be given tags and ratings. I'd rather not annote videos if the metadata is solely stored on the machine on which I do the annotating.

I ask because I don't see the metadata entered in WLPG for videos in the properties window of the file in Windows 7 Explorer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be trivial to check this? Just copy a video, edit the copy's tags, then check if the file matches the original.

Comment: @Karan I should have been more clear. No, there is no change to the file, unlike with photo tagging which works the way I expect.